# Does the application_startup() get called for each silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, prism

I am using the templates for prism by David Hill and each application module contains a App.xaml file. I was sure that each module as it was loaded would create the App object (startup object in properties) and then call the application_startup() event.

However, this does not seem to be happening? Is this correct behaviour? If so, how would I define my resources (styles etc) in a app.xaml file for each application module?

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is only for the start-up (or "master" if you will) application  that the app_start event is called. So you could include all your resources in App.xaml of *that* application. But it wouldn't necessarily have to be one single file, you can separate them using merged resource dictionaries. You'll find more info on that here:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Merged-Resource-Dictionaries-in-Silverlight-3.aspx

Comment: Thanks Henrik. The weird thing is a month ago I wrote a comment saying that the application_start() was called on each module. I remember setting breaking points on each one to see the InitParams dictionary passed. Ah well, I will look at resource dictionaries. Thanks.